# How to update a class attribute from within run() method of a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to update a class attribute (the class is extending `Thread`) in the `run()` method, I do it like so:

```
public class ClassProcessing extends Thread {

    volatile public List<String> processedList ;
    
    ...
    
    public void run() {
    
      ....
      String processedElement = ....
    
      this.processedList.add(computedElement);
    }
```

Doing like so returns `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.add(Object)" because "this.processedList" is null`

How to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you iniailized `processedList`?

Comment: no in no where in my code i did that.

Comment: You need to assign an instance of `List` to `processedList`. If it’s accessed from multiple threads, you should ensure that it’s a thread-safe implementation.

Comment: @Tim could you explain more?

Comment: volatile public List<String> processedList = new ArrayList<>();?

Comment: If i assign an instance of list as `public List<String> processedList = new ArrayList<>();` it will reinitialize the array at each thread call which i don't want

Comment: That would only initialise the array when a new instance of `ClassProcessing` is created. Each instance has its own array.

Comment: I want an array that is cross threads, where the results of each thread call is stored in it

Comment: You could make it static.

Comment: Don't extend thread, instead implement Runnable, use one instance for multiple threads, and make sure to use a synchronized list or a suitable concurrent collection

Answer (score 1):

First, you have not initialized `processedList`, or at least it's not shown in your code snippet.

Second, you use `volatile` on the `processedList` field, but this does not help to make your code thread-safe. `volatile` only affects the reference in the field itself, not the list object. Instead you should use a thread-safe class, like [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) or [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html).

Comment: could explain what do you mean by   thread-safe?

Comment: If you don't know that thread-safe means, you should read up on that before using threads. Unfortunately, this is probably not something you can do in a few minutes. There are whole classes at universities dealing with concurrency and thread-safety. One book I recommend is: https://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601

Comment: I'd recommend [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for Oracle as a good starting point. It covers the basics of the language, the collections framework, and up to advanced topics such as threads and concurrency. I agree with @rolve that writing code that uses threads is better left until after you have mastered the fundamentals.